# How to better manage the data provider package retrieved from the device memory?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, flutter-provider

I am making a mobile application with flutter, I am using provider for state management, I have a question, I have about 300 widgets on one page. When I go from one page to this page, it opens a little slowly. Is this because the widgets are re-created? The data is reflected only if it is up-to-date data. It does not work over and over again every time the build runs. I don't understand why the page is slow to open, can you help me?

class from which I pull data from device storage

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';

class GetMusicProvider extends ChangeNotifier{

  late OnAudioQuery _audioQuery;
  List<SongModel> _musicList = [];
  List<SongModel> get musicList => _musicList;

 Future<void> fetchMusic() async {
   _audioQuery = OnAudioQuery();
   _musicList = await _audioQuery.querySongs(
    sortType: SongSortType.DATE_ADDED,
    orderType: OrderType.DESC_OR_GREATER,
    uriType: UriType.EXTERNAL,  
    ignoreCase: true,
  );
  notifyListeners();
 }
}
```

the class where I show the data on the screen

When I come to this page from another page, this page opens slowly. I couldn't understand what caused this.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:music_app/consts/textStyle.dart';
import 'package:music_app/state_management/get_music_provider.dart';
import 'package:on_audio_query/on_audio_query.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class MusicListCardWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  MusicListCardWidget();

@override
State<MusicListCardWidget> createState() => _MusicListCardWidgetState();

}

class _MusicListCardWidgetState extends State<MusicListCardWidget> {
  List<SongModel> musicList = [];
  late OnAudioQuery _audioQuery;
  late AudioPlayer _audioPlayer;

 @override
  void initState() {
   _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
   super.initState();
 }

@override
 void dispose() {
  _audioPlayer.dispose();
  super.dispose();
 }

 Future<void> _playMusic(String audioPath) async {
  try {
    await _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(audioPath)));
    await _audioPlayer.play();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error playing music: $e");
  }
}

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Provider.of<GetMusicProvider>(context, listen: true).musicList.length != 0 ?  SizedBox(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: ListView.builder(
    
    itemCount: Provider.of<GetMusicProvider>(context, listen: true).musicList.length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    primary: false,
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.w),
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var musicInfo = Provider.of<GetMusicProvider>(context, listen: 
      true).musicList[index];
         // print(musicInfo.album);
       return ListTile(
          title: Text(musicInfo.displayNameWOExt, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: 1,
           style: TextStyles.musicListCardTextStyle(context),),
          subtitle: Text(
             musicInfo.artist!= '<unknown>' ?   
             musicInfo.artist.toString() :
             musicInfo.displayName.toString(),
          maxLines: 1, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),), 
          leading:  QueryArtworkWidget(id: musicInfo.id, type: ArtworkType.AUDIO),
          trailing: 
              Column(
                  children: [   
                    IconButton(icon: Icon( Icons.play_circle_outline_outlined, size: 
        30,color:TextStyles.colorMethod(index),), 
                    onPressed: () {
                       _playMusic(musicInfo.uri!);
                       print(Uri.parse(musicInfo.uri!).toString());
                      
                    },),
                   // Text('04.52'),
                  ],
                ),                 
       );
     },
    ),
   ) 
   : Center(
     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
   );
  }
 }
```

Class that supersedes MusicListCardWidget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:music_app/consts/textStyle.dart';
import 'package:music_app/state_management/get_music_provider.dart';
import 'package:music_app/state_management/theme_provider.dart';
import 'package:music_app/widgets/music_list_card.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import '../widgets/music_card.dart';

 class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
   const HomePage({super.key});
   @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
 }
  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final controller = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, keepPage: true);
      return Scaffold( 
         body:  ListView(
            children: [
               SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("En son", style: TextStyles.plyListTextStyle(context)),
                  SizedBox(width: 2.w,),
                  Icon(Icons.auto_awesome_motion_rounded)
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 2.h,), 
              SizedBox(
                height: 33.h,
                child: PageView(    
                  
                  controller: controller,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
                  ,children: [
                    MusicCardWidget( image: 'images/gazapizm.jpg',musicName: 'gazapizm'),  
                    MusicCardWidget( image: 'images/polatAlemdar.jpg', musicName: 'Polat 
      Alemdar',) ,
                    MusicCardWidget( image: 'images/sagopa.jpg', musicName: 'sagopa',)   
                  ],
                )
                ),
                
                MusicListCardWidget(),
                
            ],
          ),
       );
  

    }
   }
```